# How to get the check box click event fired in Jquery document ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In the `document.ready` function, alert is throwing an `undefined` error message.
On this check box selection, I will have to enable or disable radio button controls.

How to validate, whether checkbox : other is checked or not?

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  $("#Other").on("click", function ()
    {
       // On this check box click event, i will have to enable radio buttons 
       document.getElementById('Yes').disabled = false;
       document.getElementById('No').disabled = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What you mean with "check box click event fired"? Is that you want to (un)check all checkboxes automatically when radio button `click` event triggered? Also better provide markup of radio buttons and checkboxes to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fire click event on `document.ready` you need to trigger the click event that you have defined on element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Other").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $("#Other").trigger("click");
});
```

in the above click event on `#Other` has been defined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Other").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $("#Other").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Other" type="checkbox" value="Hello World">checkbox
```

To check if the check box is checked or not you can do

```
if ($("#Other").is(":checked")) {
    // do something if the checkbox is checked
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#Other").is(":checked")) {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true); 
  } else {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Other" type="checkbox" value="Hello World" checked>checkbox1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="radio"> radio<br>
```

To check and uncheck the checkbox your code looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Other").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true); 
  } else {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false); 
  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Other" type="checkbox" value="Hello World">checkbox1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="radio"> radio<br>
```

To enable and disable radio button you can add disable attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Other").on("click", function() {
    enblDsblChkb($(this));
  });
  
  enblDsblChkb($("#Other"));
  
  function enblDsblChkb($elem){
    if ($elem.is(":checked")) {
      $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', false); 
    } else {
      $('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true); 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Other" type="checkbox" value="Hello World">checkbox1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="no"> No<br>
```

Comment: This is Dupo of mine

Comment: @Kiran Shahi, Thank you. I am trying to enable or disable radio buttons based on check box selection which is not happening ..

Comment: @goofyui I have updated my answer hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @KiranShahi , Radiobuttons Yes or No  has to be enabled . Not checked. Yes, No are two buttons which will be enabled and available for the user to select. Not defaulting to checked

Comment: @goofyui you want that buttons disabled on checkbox checked?

Comment: On check of the checkbox, both Yes, No radio buttons should be enabled